# libpcrecpp.so.0 error in 64bit

Tags: linux-mint, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to execute a file and it throws this error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpcrecpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

I browse Synaptic Packge Manager and found this `libpcrecpp0`. I installed it and run the executable again but the same error shows.

I also installed ia32libs thinking it needs 32 libs.

System: Linux Mint 15 Olivia 64bit

Comment: Can you check if the library actually exist under `/lib` and `/usr/lib` or not? There is a simple solution if you found for example libpcrecpp.so.1 ... Just check the two locations first.

Comment: in /usr/lib, I found libpcrecpp.so.0 and libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0

Comment: This sounds strange ...
Try defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin
before running the application ...

Comment: Still the same error shows

Comment: Here is two things to try:
1 - `file /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0` to make sure the file is not a broken symlink
2 - `ldd exec_file_name` This will print for you all the dependencies and how they are resolved, you can see what you get 
2 - `strace exec_file_name` will show exactly what the program is trying to access and do
It will be more beneficial if you can update the question with the output of these two commands and the fact that you have library in /usr/lib

Comment: I installed the package libpcrecpp0:i386 and it fixed it, thought I can't find it in the Synaptic package manager.
Thank you for trying to help me. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @markuz could you write that as answer below?

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Maybe tonight.

Comment: I put together an answer that I hope clarifies the situation.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic linker/loader, `ld.so`, by default looks through the library paths, as defined in the `ld.so.conf`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and on the command-line if `ld.so` is executed explicitly.

If will attempt to load dynamic libraries (aka shared objects) as-needed using the name of the shared object from one of those paths, and keeps trying until successful.  Attempts to load a shared object that is not compatible (e.g. a 64-bit shared object is incompatible with a 32-bit executable), it will ignore the incompatible object.

To get more information on the executable and shared objects, the following programs can be used:

```
ldd
strace
file
```

If the program is 32-bit, installing the 32-bit version of the library is required.  Likewise for a 64-bit program.

Comment: I already solved it but thank you for this useful information.